# Using a search bar to filter through values in a BIG nested JSON in Javascript (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter

I'm trying to create a search bar to filter through TITLES within the nested JSON.

Here's a small sample of the structure of my JSON.

```
listOfArticles = {
     "HOME": {
          "0": {
               "title": "Wall Street CEOs try to come up with new plan for First Republic",
               "link": "www.ft.com/content/b67d2ab3-03bc-49fd-ac60-887373a64137"},
          "1": {
               "title": "Markets Briefing",
               "link": "www.ft.com/content/d1d3acd2-af70-4348-b617-406ce11ca259"},
          "2": {
               "title": "Bid deadline for failed Silicon Valley Bank is extended as buyers hold back",
               "link": "www.ft.com/content/2cbd90b6-dbca-4589-a8db-7195940fba8e"}
     }
     WORLD": {
           "0": {
                "title": "Xi praises Putin\u2019s \u2018strong leadership\u2019 in Kremlin talks",
                "link": "www.ft.com/content/c82f1a91-8b60-40b6-81d9-494cf7ec2325"},
           "1": {
                "title": "IMF approves $3bn bailout for Sri Lanka ",
                "link": "www.ft.com/content/96b9bee1-401c-418e-b92a-3e7cfb6d59a6"},
           "2": {
                "title": "VW\u2019s plans to pull out of Russia
                "link": "www.ft.com/content/7ecb9822-d6d0-4186-9dad-4943fbde31a4"}
     } 
     "UK"  : {
          "0": {
               "title": "London police force should be overhauled or broken up, says review",
               "link": "www.ft.com/content/a9467416-a7ea-4611-9554-b69d50aafd4d"}
          "1": {
               "title": "Labour calls for review of impact of financial sector uncertainty on UK ",
               "link": "www.ft.com/content/6a48d3d2-20a8-4059-98fd-1965196051fd"},
          "2": {
               "title": "Sturgeon admits SNP leadership election has been \u2018difficult\u2019",
               "link": "www.ft.com/content/9658b054-6483-499f-94b9-94eb2f992660"}
     }
```

And this is my code...

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const [searchWord, setSearchWord] = useState("")

  const filteredArticles = Object.keys(listOfArticles).map(page => {
    return (
      Object.keys(listOfArticles[page]).filter(function(item){
        console.log(listOfArticles[page][item].title) //This log works as expected
        return (
          <div>
            {listOfArticles[page][item].title.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase())}
          </div>
        )
      })
    )
  })

console.log(filteredArticles)
return (
    <div>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Search...' onChange={ (userInput) => {
        setSearchWord(userInput.target.value)
        }}/>
        {filteredArticles}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried replacing `Object.keys()` with `Object.entries()` too, but not sure if I used it correctly.

I've removed a fair chunk of code in the bottom return which can loop through the unfiltered JSON without a problem.

WHAT I WANT TO DO:
Currently `filteredArticles` returns an array, but it's not even close to what I want. I want it to return a JSON to be in the exact same format, and with objects that aren't in the search term removed. Objects i.e. `{"0": {"title": ###, "link": ###}}`

[filteredArticles Output ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N6xe.png)

Many thanks.

Comment: You'll be converting objects to arrays and back again with data structured like that.  Consider using arrays instead where suitable, ie there is no useful difference between `{"0": "thing1", "1": "thing2}` and `["thing1", "thing2"]`

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before you use a tag. The JSON tag contains: _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals."_ Your question is unrelated to JSON. If you have JSON, parse it. If you want to return JSON, serialize it. But that shouldn't be part of the problem. Questions should isolate the actual problem and remove unnecessary context.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to change object to arrays as if you always have "0", "1", etc as a key it is not really nescessary. Arrays also have stronger guarantees of ordering.

```
listOfArticles = {
     "HOME": [{
               "title": "Wall Street CEOs try to come up with new plan for First Republic",
               "link": "www.ft.com/content/b67d2ab3-03bc-49fd-ac60-887373a64137"
              },
              ]
}
```

In your case it is important to make sure your understand filter and map functions. If you return something from filter it will be included in the final render and since you are always returning  it is not useful.

You need to split it in 2 step process to first filter all rows you want and then show them.

```js
const filteredArticles = Object.keys(listOfArticles).map(page => {
    return (
      Object.keys(listOfArticles[page])
      .filter(function(item){
        console.log(listOfArticles[page][item].title) //This log works as expected
        
        return listOfArticles[page][item].title.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase())
      })
      .map(function (item) {
        // here you should have already filtered rows
        return (
          <div>
            {listOfArticles[page][item].title}
          </div>
        )
      })
    )
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I've changed the objects into array as you suggested. However unfortunately the problem still remains as I am using "Realtime Firebase" to store the data, and it automatic converts the format you suggested into the one in my original post 

I've also tried converting objects to array after pulling the data from Firebase, but I'm not sure why I see the same thing as previously in console.log() `{"0": {"title": ###, "link": ###}}`

Comment: I forgot to mention that your code does solve my problem, thanks :). My comment above was just because I was curious why I wasn't able to convert object to array.